# index out of range

Tags: python

Написал код для подсчёта энтропии. Во время удаления элемента равного нулю пишет out of range. Я не могу понять, почему ему не хватает.

```
from math import log

def entropy():
    s = input()
    a = '0123456789'
    am = []
    pa = []
    for i in range(len(a)):
        am.append(s.count(a[i]))
        if am[i] == 0:
            am.remove(am[i])
    for i in range(len(am)):
        p = float(am[i]/len(s))
        l = log(p, len(a))
        f = l * p
        pa.append(f)
    w = sum(pa)
    if w < 0:
        w = w * -1
    print(w)

entropy()
```

Comment: Ошибка не воспроизводится. Программа работает совершенно нормально. На каком тесте она вылетает?

Comment: Добавь отладочную печать (``print(am)`` например) и посмотри что у тебя в списке и к чему ты пытаешься обращаться.

Comment: Если вы удалили какой-то элемент из `am`, то его длина уменьшится на единицу, и на следующем шаге будет обращение за край списка. Не проще ли просто **не добавлять** нулевые элементы?

Comment: Правильно сформулированная проблема: в время обращения к списку по несуществующему индексу. А совсем не "во время удаления элемента равного нулю".